# Image in Adaptive card inside Action.ShowCard button in showing undefined

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an Adaptive card the code is below. The problem I am facing is The card that will be displayed after clicking the `Action.ShowCard` button can not render Image. It says `undefined`. The same image gets displayed when I use it in a normal card. I think it cannot render the image that is in the card of the button. To test it you can copy the code in your `App Studio's UI Tool` and click `Send me this card`

**Screen shot of what I get**

[image]

**Main code**

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
    ],
    "actions":[
        {
            "type": "Action.ShowCard",
            "title": "Action.ShowCard",
            "card": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "version": "1.2",
                "msteams": {
                    "entities": []
                },
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "auto",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Image",
                                        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png",
                                        "size": "Small"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "text": "Color theorysdjkf",
                                        "wrap": true,
                                        "weight": "Bolder",
                                        "color": "Attention"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "verticalContentAlignment": "Center"
                            }
                        ],
                        "height": "stretch",
                        "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                        "separator": true,
                        "spacing": "Large"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "wrap": true,
                        "spacing": "Small",
                        "text": "You selected **A**"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "ColumnSet",
                        "columns": [
                            {
                                "type": "Column",
                                "width": "stretch",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "TextBlock",
                                        "wrap": true,
                                        "text": "This is a long explanation for the answer and I think it is getting so long  and long and long long long long "
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "style": "emphasis",
                        "spacing": "Small"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "style": "positive"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you add wikimedia to your app's domain whitelist? As far as i know MS Teams only allows images to be loaded from whatever you have whitelisted in your app definitions. Images must come from a whitelisted domain.

Comment: If that is the problem then why it is showing in the main card. I mean if I use the same image in the main card it is showing. But if I use it in the ShwCard button's card it is not showing. I will still check making it whitelisted

Comment: No @TimCadenbach I have added the domain but no luck

Comment: hmm weird... its working fine in AdaptiveCardStudio, Designer and even Outlook....a bit lost here i only know that MS Teams is "doing something" in the background if you check the image url you'll see its routed through some MS Server. Usually this is a problem with images behind authenticated resources but thats not the case here tho

Comment: Yeap right. That's so wired

Comment: @TimCadenbach that's definitely not required for Card images, that the domain be listed in the app manifest. It is correct though that it must be anonymously accessible (e.g. -Microsoft- SharePoint Online images can't be shown in -Microsoft- Teams - I think it's pre-fetching images and caching them on the user's behalf (e.g. CDN), which is why that applies.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow is right Slack also does that. That is for caching.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is a platform issue.
We have raised a bug for it.
We will let you know once it is resolved.
Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, Can you let me know where is the place to raise the bug?

Comment: moshfiqrony - This is already raised internally. Fix for this is also checked in but pending the rollout. We will let you know once it's avaialable in publicly.

Comment: @moshfiqrony - ahh, I could see that you had raised in on GitHub as well. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/3671

You can use that thread to track it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried base64 encoding the image (and tried a very small minified version - 23k), but that also failed. It looks like a bug to me. There are several Microsoft people here on Stack Overflow so they'll pick this up and feed it back if they can repro it (which they should have no trouble doing).

Comment: Do you know a better way than this to reach MS peoples. I have posted an issue to their github repo

Comment: They're generally pretty good with monitoring these things, but can take a few days to spot the issue.